# How to join table from and compare id with main id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

When I try to get result I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The multi-part identifier "res.MainStaying" could not be bound.

```
select * 
from ConvictedPersons as cp
inner  join (
    select * 
    from Person 
    where ID = cp.id
) as hp 
    on hp.ID is not null

select hrt.NameRU, r2as.ID, res.* 
from PunishmentMeasure as pm  
    inner join CourtDecisions as cd 
        on cd.ID = pm.CourtDecisionID
    inner join Resolutions as res 
        on res.ID = cd.ResolutionID
    left join  ( 
        select top 1 * 
        from Resolutions 
        where MainStayingID = res.MainStayingID 
        order by ID DESC
    ) as r2as 
        on r2as.ID is not null
```

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct because `hrt` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery that is a part of the `From` (or `join`) clause don't have access to the main query, that's why you get the error message.
(BTW, on the first select you should get the same error, just on `cp.id` instead of `res.MainStayingID`)

The first query can be fixed by simplification:

```
select * 
from ConvictedPersons as cp
inner join Person
    on Person.ID = cp.Id
```

The second query can be fixed by changing the `left join` to a correlated subquery:

```
select  hrt.NameRU, 
        (
            select top 1 ID 
            from Resolutions 
            where MainStayingID = res.MainStayingID 
            order by ID DESC
        ) as ID, 
        res.* 
from PunishmentMeasure as pm  
inner join CourtDecisions as cd 
    on cd.ID = pm.CourtDecisionID
inner join Resolutions as res 
    on res.ID = cd.ResolutionID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter your subquery with outer table columns, you can use `cross or outer apply`

```
select hrt.NameRU, r2as.ID, res.* 
from PunishmentMeasure as pm  
    inner join CourtDecisions as cd 
        on cd.ID = pm.CourtDecisionID
    inner join Resolutions as res 
        on res.ID = cd.ResolutionID
    outer apply ( 
        select top 1 * 
        from Resolutions 
        where MainStayingID = res.MainStayingID 
        order by ID DESC
    ) as r2as
```

Comment: That was my initial though as well, however when you read the query you realize that the derived table is actually completely equivalent to a correlated subquery, since the main query only ever use the `ID` column can can simply return just this single scalar value and therefor no need for the `select *` or the `apply` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use window functions?

```
select hrt.NameRU, res.* 
from PunishmentMeasure pm inner join
     CourtDecisions cd 
     on cd.ID = pm.CourtDecisionID inner join
     (select res.*,
             min(res.id) over (partition by res.MainStayingID) as min_id
      from Resolutions res 
     ) res
     on res.ID = cd.ResolutionID
-- where min_id is not null;
```

I find the comparison on `r2as.ID is not null` to be superfluous.  A column called `id` should never be `null` and I would expect a match based on the other conditions in the query.

I don't even think you need a subquery here (but you haven't explained the logic or provided sample data and desired results):

```
select hrt.NameRU,
       min(res.id) over (partition by res.MainStayingID) as min_id,
       res.* 
from PunishmentMeasure pm inner join
     CourtDecisions cd 
     on cd.ID = pm.CourtDecisionID inner join
     Resolutions res 
     on res.ID = cd.ResolutionID;
```

These solutions ignore the issue that `hrt` is undefined in your query.